# How to design html form properly

Tags: html, css

I just started web development few days back so having problem in designing form. I am making an form using html and css but it is not designed as i need.
I tried it by putting label and input in 1 div and then float label to left side and input to right side but its not work properly.

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4ayp.png)

[I designed this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xj4v.png)

**Snippet**

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form {
  width: 50%;
}

.group {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.group label {
  float: left;
}

.inputrow input {
  float: right;
}

.inputrow input:not(.col-3) {
  width: 80%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 20%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<p>New Contact</p>
<hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" />

<div class="form">
  <div class="group">
    <lable>Primary Contact</lable>
    <div class="inputrow">
      <select class="col-3">
        <option>Mr.</option>
        <option>Mrs.</option>
        <option>Ms.</option>
        <option>Miss.</option>
        <option>Dr.</option>
      </select>
      <input class="col-3" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" />
      <input class="col-3" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LastName" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <div class="inputrow">
      <input class="col-1" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompanyName" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Contact Email</label>
    <div class="inputrow">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Email" name="Email" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Contact Phone</label>
    <div class="inputrow">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Phone" name="Phone" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Website</label>
    <div class="inputrow">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Website" name="Website" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Contact Type</label>
    <div class="inputrow">
      <input type="radio" name="contacttype" value="Customer">Customer
      <input type="radio" name="contacttype" value="Vendor">Vendor
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using `float` is bad practice as it gets your elements out of their normal document flow. take a look at `flex` instead and you could easily accomplish what you want

Comment: So i have to make 2 divs. 1 for all label and 1 for all input. Then i have to use flex right? @MihaiT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you're trying to achieve is clearly all left aligned.

You could go for a solution like this (simpler and cleaner) :

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
}

label,
input,
select {
  float: left;
}

label {
  width: 150px;
}

.m-right {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>New Contact</p>
<hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" />

<div class="form">
  <div class="group">
    <label>Primary Contact</label>
    <select class="m-right">
      <option>Mr.</option>
      <option>Mrs.</option>
      <option>Ms.</option>
      <option>Miss.</option>
      <option>Dr.</option>
    </select>
    <input class="m-right" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LastName" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompanyName" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Contact Email</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Email" name="Email" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Contact Phone</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Phone" name="Phone" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Website</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Website" name="Website" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>Contact Type</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contacttype" value="Customer">Customer</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="contacttype" value="Vendor">Vendor</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select Select box and radio. You should need to put some html.

```css
body,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.form{
width:50%;
}
.group{
width:100%;
margin:20px;
}
.group label{
float:left;
}
.inputrow input,.inputrow select,.inputrow select{
float:right;
}
.inputrow input:not(.col-3){
width:80%;
 }
.col-3{
width:20%;
 }
.clear{
clear:both;
}
.inputrow input[type=radio]{
 width:auto;
 float:left;
}
.inputrow div{
  width:40%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>New Contact</p>
    <hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;" />

<div class="form">
<div class="group">
<lable>Primary Contact</lable>
<div class="inputrow">
    <select class="col-3">
        <option>Mr.</option>
        <option>Mrs.</option>
        <option>Ms.</option>
        <option>Miss.</option>
        <option>Dr.</option>
    </select>
    <input class="col-3" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName"/>
    <input class="col-3" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LastName"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="group">
<label>Company Name</label>
<div class="inputrow">
    <input class="col-1" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompanyName"/>     
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="group">
<label>Contact Email</label>
<div class="inputrow">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Email" name="Email"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="group">
<label>Contact Phone</label>
<div class="inputrow">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Phone" name="Phone"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="group">
<label>Website</label>
<div class="inputrow">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Website" name="Website"/> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="group">
<label>Contact Type</label>
<div class="inputrow">
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="contacttype" value="Vendor">Vendor
    </div>
     <div>
    <input type="radio" name="contacttype" value="Customer">Customer
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout you want can be achieved by using the grid system. Example can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp). where you devide each row up into its parts removing the need to float elements.

As for the actual styling I would suggest looking at the developer tools on the website your example is on and see what styling is applied to each element. Which on Chrome can be accessed by pressing **F12** on the keyboard.